# Copy Paste Range not copying all values in range

Tags: excel, vba, range, copy-paste

I am trying to copy cells starting from C4 to D123 in one sheet and pasting it into a new worksheet starting on column D13. The range is dynamic so it is not always going to end at D123, but it should always start at C4. My issue right now is that it looks like i'm only copying and pasting 9 of the cells instead of everything from C4:D123 in one instance. The sheet i'm copying from looks like this:

[image]

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim targetws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim TransactionColumn As Variant

TransactionColumn = "D"
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, TransactionColumn).End(xlUp).Row

Set targetws = Sheets("targetwsname")

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ws.Name Like "*" & " - Pay" & "*" Then
        ws.Range("C4:D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy Destination:=targetws.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End If
Next ws
```

End Sub

Comment: `Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` does not have a parent sheet, so it is using the activesheet.  You probably want: `ws.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, SCOTT!! That fixed everything :') I can't believe i missed that...Thank you again!